# Add multiple config lines below a certain block via bash command

Tags: linux, bash

I have a config file `app.ini` (the background is [gitea](https://gitea.io), but that is not important)

```
[log]
MODE      = file
LEVEL     = info

[server]
SSH_DOMAIN       = localhost
DOMAIN           = localhost
HTTP_PORT        = 3000

[mailer]
ENABLED = false
```

I would like to add multiple lines at the end of the `[server]` block via a bash command (without open and edit app.ini). How to add something to the end is clear (`echo "xyz" >> app.ini`).

The result should be something like:

```
[log]
MODE      = file
LEVEL     = info

[server]
SSH_DOMAIN       = localhost
DOMAIN           = localhost
HTTP_PORT        = 3000
PROTOCOL = https
CERT_FILE = cert.pem
KEY_FILE = key.pem

[mailer]
ENABLED = false
```

Adding the new lines below `[server]` is also fine:

```
[server]
PROTOCOL = https
CERT_FILE = cert.pem
KEY_FILE = key.pem
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's incredible, how easy it is sometimes to find a solution by using a search engine. You should try one from time to time: http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/insert-line-before-or-after-pattern.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Which keywords to type to find this page?

Comment: after the HTTP_PORT is also fine for that pattern?

Comment: @Jetchisel after HTTP_PORT would be perfect.

Comment: With the link from @fancyPants this is how I worked out a simple solution `sed -i 's/^\[server\].*/&\nPROTOCOL = https\nCERT_FILE = cert.pem\nKEY_FILE = key.pem/' a`

Comment: Ok, you have a working solution then.

Comment: Well, a trivial solution. How would you match the pattern HTTP_PORT and tabs till equal sign?

Comment: `/^HTTP_PORT[[:space:]]*=.*`

Comment: Could you post it as an answer please. That's I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ed` and bash.

```sh
printf '%s\n' '/^\[server\]/,/^HTTP_PORT[[:space:]]*=.*/a' $'POROTOCOL = https\nCERT_FILE = cert.pem\nKEY_FILE = key.pem' . ,p Q | ed -s app.ini
```

Or you can save that multiline strings in a separate file, and create an `ed` script that has the following code.

```sh
H
/^\[server\]$/,/^HTTP_PORT[[:space:]]*=.*/r insert.txt
,p
Q
```

- Where `insert.txt` contains your strings to insert and `script.ed` is the script.

Then

```
ed -s app.ini < script.ed
```

- Change the `Q` to `w` if you think that the output is correct, to edit the `app.ini`

Without the separate config file, the script looks something like this.

```sh
H
/^\[server\]/,/^HTTP_PORT[[:space:]]*=.*/a                           
POROTOCOL = https
CERT_FILE = cert.pem
KEY_FILE = key.pem
.
,p
Q
```

Then same syntax for calling the script against the file.

```
ed -s app.ini < script.ed
```

Comment: I'm trying `ed` but getting `?` as result.

Comment: The first code in one-line is specific to `bash`, try the other solution with a script since it should work on any Unix shell

Comment: And make sure you don't have carriage returns on the files.

Answer (score 1):

A pure bash version :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFS+=$'\r' # Handle possible carriage returns
while read -r line; do
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
    test "$line" = "[server]" && cat << EOF
PROTOCOL         = https
CERT_FILE        = cert.pem
KEY_FILE         = key.pem
EOF
done < app.ini
```